# Unable to access Manager app on Tomcat 7.0.39

Tags: tomcat, tomcat-manager

I'm unable to access the manager app.

I've added the manager-gui role to the tomcat-users.xml file ...& added the same role to the tomcat user, ...

```
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,manager-gui"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

... I've also tried this to no avail ...

```
<tomcat-users>
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
  <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui"/> 
</tomcat-users>
```

Is there something else I need to do?  The docs read that this is all that is necessary ...

I've stopped & restarted the server after all changes ...

Comment: What do you see when you try to access `\manager`?
Do you see Basic Authentication popup?

Comment: It work for me with this: `<role rolename="manager-gui"/><role rolename="tomcat"/> <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat, manager-gui"/>`

Answer (score 1):

Starting the service with "service tomcat7 start/restart" will fix your problem

Answer (score 1):

@ Eclipse

Access the file "tomcat-users.xml" @ C:\Users\MyUserName\workspace\Servers\Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost-config\

and add the lines...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <tomcat-users>
        <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
        <user username="tomcat" password="12345" roles="manager-gui"/>
    </tomcat-users>
```

Hopefully this will fix the problem.