# Tomcat7 manager-gui login fail

Tags: linux, authentication, tomcat7

I cannot login to http://[myip]:8080/manager/html on tomcat7.

I have tried:

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="admin" password="s3cret" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

in tomcat-users.xml and restarted. (The xml-code is not commented!) Doesn't work. I've tried changing the memory realm according to (what is this?):
[Unable to access Manager app on Tomcat 7.0.39](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15999618/unable-to-access-manager-app-on-tomcat-7-0-39)

Doesn't work.

The authentication dialog pops up, but as soon as I have entered admin / s3cret the dialog comes back blank again, not letting me in. Am I editing the wrong file or is it not used or what could possibly be going on?

Please help.

Comment: What is your Linux distribution?

Comment: I feel insecure regarding what to write in servers.xml. Should I for example keep the LockOutRealm and the UserDatabaseRealm and add MemoryRealm (inside this tag or outside?). I also don't know how to set $CATALINA_HOME. I just used apt-get install. Is it set then? If I write env then I don't see it but if I use export ... then it doesn't help. Also config files don't seem to use $CATALINA_HOME. There's a lot I am uncertain about here.

Comment: $CATALINA_HOME etc seem to be set correctly.